# Critical Values of the Chi-Square Distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am trying to reproduce the (upper-tail) critical values of chi-square distribution with ν degrees of freedom as reported [here](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3674.htm). As a test I looked at $\nu=2$ and the probability $0.99$.

As far as I can tell, in Mathematica the ChiSquare distribution is implemented in `ChiSquareDistribution`, so here is what I tried to do to find the value:

`NIntegrate[PDF[ChiSquareDistribution[2], x], {x, 99/100, Infinity}]`

However, this gives `0.609571`. Do I need to scale this value to get the desired result?

Comment: `Quantile[ChiSquareDistribution[2], .99]` or `NSolve[CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[2], t] == 99/100, t, Reals]`?

Comment: `InverseCDF[ChiSquareDistribution[2],99/100]` as well.

Comment: Or working from the `PDF`: `FindRoot[Integrate[PDF[ChiSquareDistribution[2], x], {x, 0, xf}] == 
   0.99`, {xf, 1}] // Quiet` or `Assuming[xf > 0, 
  Solve[Integrate[PDF[ChiSquareDistribution[2], x], {x, 0, xf}] == 
    0.99`, xf]] // Quiet`

Comment: For your question "Do I need to scale this value to get the desired result?", the answer is "No.  You've formulated the statement incorrectly to obtain the desired result."  To obtain 0.99 you'd need to use `NIntegrate[PDF[ChiSquareDistribution[2], x], {x, 0, 9.21034}]`.  To obtain the desired value (9.21034) you'd need to follow any of the above comments.

Answer (score 3):

```
N @ Quantile[ChiSquareDistribution[2], 99/100]
```

> 9.21034

```
t /.  First@ NSolve[CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[2], t] == 99/100, t, Reals]
```

> 9.21034

Or, modifying the formulation in OP:

```
t /. First @ NSolve[Integrate[PDF[ChiSquareDistribution[2], x], {x, 0, t}, 
     Assumptions -> Element[t, Reals]] == 99/100, t, Reals]
```

> 9.21034